# Packaging a PyQt5 app for Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm running into a problem trying to package a PyQt program as a Mac OS application.

I can create the app using cx_Freeze, but when I open the app it quits unexpectedly. In the console it shows the error that there are two versions Qt installed on the computer and it can't decide which one to use. One version is in the app I just made and the other is in `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/...`

How do I get around this? The script works totally fine not packaged as an app.

**EDIT:**

Adding the errors and `setup.py`

Console readout:

```
objc[56464]: Class NotificationReceiver is implemented in both /path/to/the.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWidgets and /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.1_2/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[56464]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /path/to/the.app/Contents/MacOS/QtPrintSupport and /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.1_2/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[56464]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /path/to/the.app/Contents/MacOS/QtPrintSupport and /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.1_2/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

`setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages=[], excludes=[])

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform == 'win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('qt_test.py', base=base)
]

setup(
    name='SpamEggs',
    version='0.1',
    description='The Description',
    options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
    executables=executables
)
```

Comment: Can you show exact, literal error you get? FWIW I had a lot of trouble with cx_Freeze and switched to [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) which works a lot better for me.

Comment: You should post both the error you are given and you setup.py otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: Sorry for not including these before, I have added the errors and setup.py file.

Comment: @TheCompiler I followed your suggestion of using pyinstaller and that works! Nothing else needed. Still wondering if there's a solution to the above...

Comment: Now that I see the error I actually remember having that as well with `cx_Freeze` and not finding a solution.